# What is the 'Steam-Chill-Bake' method of making hot wings?

Tags: baking, chicken

[This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/trouble-with-baked-chicken-wings) had a response mentioning the 'Steam-Chill-Bake' method.  What is that?  Why would someone cook wings this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're referring to my comment and it was actually referring to [my answer to the question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6626/trouble-with-baked-chicken-wings/6631#6631).  To summarize (follow the link for specific instructions), the technique is:

- Steam the wings for 10 minutes
- Season, then chill them in the refrigerator for 1 hour
- Bake at high temperature (450° F) for 20 minutes on each side
- Toss with sauce.

Why cook them this way?  Because it makes them perfectly crispy and juicy, almost like deep-fried wings (better, if you ask me).  Assuming the sauce has an appropriate amount of fat (butter) then it will also bind perfectly.